# Is re.search() slower since Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, python-2.x, python-re

I have two questions about python `re` module.

I updated my application of python version to 3.7. After I did so, I noticed a slowdown in the `re.search()`.
I did simple test, it may be that the average time has increased since Python 3.7.
In my app, the regular expression pattern is different every time. Therefore, there is no need to use `re.compile()`.

- simple test

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
import timeit

def func():
    for _ in range(100):
        re.search(r'\d+', 'hoge123fuga')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    max_time = 0
    min_time = 1e9
    results = []
    for _ in range(10):
        result = timeit.timeit(lambda: func, number=10000)
        if result < min_time:
            min_time = result
        if max_time < result:
            max_time = result
        results.append(result)

    average_time = float(sum(results)) / float(10)

    print('max_time: {}'.format(max_time))
    print('average_time: {}'.format(average_time))
    print('min_time: {}'.format(min_time))
```

- simple test results

```
python_version, average_time
2.7.17, 0.721276259422
3.5.9,  0.7110545930016088
3.6.10, 0.7553750206978294
3.7.6,  0.8779164923000001
3.8.1,  0.7880382750000001
```

So I have two questions.

1. Is re.search () slower since Python 3.7? Why is this?
2. Is it possible to make `re.search()` of Python3.7 as fast as Python 2.x?

Thank you for reading my question.

- My environment

  - macOS Catalina
  - Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8569U CPU @ 2.80GHz
  - 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3

Comment: `timeit(lambda: func())` what's the point of this? This only adds an indirection. Use `timeit(func, number=10000)`. It might be that Python 3.7.10 for some reason has slower lambda calls and this would slow down the profiling artificially.

Comment: You're also timing the loop over the range...

Comment: @GACy20 Thanks for the advice! Sorry for the wrong test code. I have fixed the bug in my test and re-measured it. Python 2.x's results and Python 3.7's result are near, but python3.7 seems to be a little slower.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Thanks for the advice! I'm sorry, I'm not good at English and I didn't understand your point. Is there anything wrong with my test script?

Comment: I don't have python 3.7 installed, however on my machine python 3.8.5 is about 25% *faster* than python2.7.18 in this case.I'm not sure whether your question will have a clear answer or whether the answer is going to simply be "performance is a function of the algorithm, hardware, compiler optimizations, dynamic load of the systems, OS scheduling etc and you just happen to have this side effect". Being able to specifically determine the reason for the performance difference in this case would require access to your hardware & software. Certainly it's not simply "python3 is slower in general"

Comment: You showed the average times, which can be higher than the actually achievable time due to process scheduling, etc. What do you get when you print the *minimum* times instead (which you already compute, but don't show)?